# REST Webserivce won't update after change in Database

Tags: java, web-services, postgresql, rest, netbeans

Hello everyone I'm trying to use REST WEbservice to communicate with a Database.
For this project I'm using Netbeans 8.1, Struts 1.3 and REST Webservice the programming language is Java.

I have a bigger project that I'm working on and there is a problem. It is not recognizing changes in the database during runtime. 
 There is a table in the database called 'cardreader' and a table called 'chipcards'. The cardreader has an id, the chipcards id as foreignkey and a timestamp. The chipcard has an id, a permissions id, a checksum and a timestamp.

**Cardreader:**

```
+----------------+---------+-------------------------+
| reader_id      | card_id | ts_lastupdate           |
+----------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 192.168.178.21 |    1004 | 2015-02-08 20:14:25.401 |
+----------------+---------+-------------------------+
```

**Chipcard:**

```
+------+---------------+----------------+-------------------------+
| id   | permission_id | checksum       | ts_lastupdate           |
+------+---------------+----------------+-------------------------+
| 1002 |             1 | 20141106142003 | 2015-01-22 22:02:50.956 |
| 1003 |             1 | 20141022002939 | 2015-01-22 22:03:00.469 |
| 1004 |             1 | 20141022210457 | 2015-01-22 22:03:13.108 |
| 1005 |             2 | 20141022002737 | 2015-01-22 22:03:17.336 |
| 1006 |             1 | 20141022002736 | 2015-01-22 22:03:25.968 |
| 1007 |             3 | 20141029163510 | 2015-01-22 22:03:29.645 |
+------+---------------+----------------+-------------------------+
```

In my program I can enter the 'reader_id' which is then looked up in the database. If the reader_id is found I'm getting back a Cardreader object in which the 'card_id' is stored. 
The problem is, if I start the program and enter a readerid I'm getting back the matching chipcard, however if i then change the 'card_id' in the cardreader table from the database (let's say to 1002) the program still returns 1004. 
As mentioned at the begging I'm using REST Webservices and Netbeans. With Netbeans you can generate 'RESTful Webservice from Database' and from the FacadeREST class you can generate the 'Java Jersey Client'.

Here you can have a look at the classes 
**AbstractFacade**

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.accounting.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Tobias
 */
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findAll() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public int count() {
        javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }

}
```

**CardreaderFacade**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.accounting.service;

import com.accounting.Cardreader;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 *
 * @author Tobias
 */
@javax.ejb.Stateless
@Path("com.accounting.cardreader")
public class CardreaderFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Cardreader> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebApplication1PU")
    private EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("WebApplication1PU").createEntityManager();

    public CardreaderFacadeREST() {
        super(Cardreader.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(Cardreader entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void edit(@PathParam("id") String id, Cardreader entity) {
        super.edit(entity);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public Cardreader find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return super.find(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Override
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Cardreader> findAll() {
        return super.findAll();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{from}/{to}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Cardreader> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
        return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

}
```

**CardreaderJerseyClient**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.accountng.client;

import javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;

/**
 * Jersey REST client generated for REST resource:CardreaderFacadeREST
 * [com.accounting.cardreader]<br>
 * USAGE:
 * <pre>
 *        CardreaderJerseyClient client = new CardreaderJerseyClient();
 *        Object response = client.XXX(...);
 *        // do whatever with response
 *        client.close();
 * </pre>
 *
 * @author Tobias
 */
public class CardreaderJerseyClient {
    private WebTarget webTarget;
    private Client client;
    private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8081/WebApplication1/webresources";

    public CardreaderJerseyClient() {
        client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
        webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("com.accounting.cardreader");
    }

    public String countREST() throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        resource = resource.path("count");
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
    }

    public void edit_XML(Object requestEntity, String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        webTarget.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{id})).request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    }

    public void edit_JSON(Object requestEntity, String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        webTarget.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{id})).request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).put(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    public <T> T find_XML(Class<T> responseType, String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{id}));
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
    }

    public <T> T find_JSON(Class<T> responseType, String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{id}));
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
    }

    public <T> T findRange_XML(Class<T> responseType, String from, String to) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", new Object[]{from, to}));
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
    }

    public <T> T findRange_JSON(Class<T> responseType, String from, String to) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}/{1}", new Object[]{from, to}));
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
    }

    public void create_XML(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
        webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    }

    public void create_JSON(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
        webTarget.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    public <T> T findAll_XML(Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(responseType);
    }

    public <T> T findAll_JSON(Class<T> responseType) throws ClientErrorException {
        WebTarget resource = webTarget;
        return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
    }

    public void remove(String id) throws ClientErrorException {
        webTarget.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{id})).request().delete();
    }

    public void close() {
        client.close();
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html"%>
    <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

    <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic"  prefix="logic"%>

    <html:form action="/checkCard">
        <html:text property="name" value="192.168.178.21">Cardreader IP</html:text>
        <html:submit property="submitValue">SEND</html:submit>
    </html:form>

**checkCard**

    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.tobias.actions;

    import com.accounting.Cardreader;
    import com.accounting.Chipcards;
    import com.accountng.client.CardreaderJerseyClient;
    import com.tobias.beans.infoBean;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

    /**
     *
     * @author Tobias
     */
    public class checkCard extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

        /* forward name="success" path="" */
        private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

        /**
         * This is the action called from the Struts framework.
         *
         * @param mapping The ActionMapping used to select this instance.
         * @param form The optional ActionForm bean for this request.
         * @param request The HTTP Request we are processing.
         * @param response The HTTP Response we are processing.
         * @throws java.lang.Exception
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws Exception {

            String readerIP;
            infoBean formBean = (infoBean) form;
            readerIP = formBean.getName();
            System.out.println("READER IP: " + readerIP);

            CardreaderJerseyClient cjc = new CardreaderJerseyClient();
            if(cjc == null){
                System.out.println("JERSEYCLIENT IST NULL");
            }
            Cardreader reader = cjc.find_XML(Cardreader.class, readerIP);
            if(reader != null){
                System.out.println("READER IP = " + reader.getReaderId());

                Chipcards card = reader.getCardId();
                if(card != null){
                    System.out.println("CHIPCARD ID = " + card.getId().toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No card found);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No reader found");
            }


            return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
        }
    }
```

**struts-config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">


<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="infoBean" type="com.tobias.beans.infoBean"/>

    </form-beans>

    <global-exceptions>

    </global-exceptions>

    <action-mappings>
        <action name="infoBean" path="/checkCard" scope="request" type="com.tobias.actions.checkCard" validate="false">
            <forward name="success" path="/index.jsp"/>
        </action>
        <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>

    <controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor"/>

    <message-resources parameter="com/myapp/struts/ApplicationResource"/>    

    <!-- ========================= Tiles plugin ===============================-->
    <!--
    This plugin initialize Tiles definition factory. This later can takes some
    parameters explained here after. The plugin first read parameters from
    web.xml, thenoverload them with parameters defined here. All parameters
    are optional.
    The plugin should be declared in each struts-config file.
    - definitions-config: (optional)
    Specify configuration file names. There can be several comma
    separated file names (default: ?? )
    - moduleAware: (optional - struts1.1)
    Specify if the Tiles definition factory is module aware. If true
    (default), there will be one factory for each Struts module.
    If false, there will be one common factory for all module. In this
    later case, it is still needed to declare one plugin per module.
    The factory will be initialized with parameters found in the first
    initialized plugin (generally the one associated with the default
    module).
    true : One factory per module. (default)
    false : one single shared factory for all modules
    - definitions-parser-validate: (optional)
    Specify if xml parser should validate the Tiles configuration file.
    true : validate. DTD should be specified in file header (default)
    false : no validation

    Paths found in Tiles definitions are relative to the main context.
    -->
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin" >
        <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />      
        <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
    </plug-in>

    <!-- ========================= Validator plugin ================================= -->
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property
            property="pathnames"
            value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml"/>
    </plug-in>

</struts-config>
```

**Afterword** 
If you are still reading: Thank you! I know i've posted a lot of code and I'm not sure if my descriptions are well enough to understand everything but I'm german so please be patient with me. 
I have some small knowledge of this REST stuff still I don't fully understand whats going.
To sum it up, I don't understand why my program reads the first card_id form the database correct but when I then change the value in the database by hand and the program is still running it's not updating.

Thank you once more for reader through this wall of text. If you have any idea what it could be or if you need further explanations just let me know :)

**edit**
okay some more information on what i have noticed. The program also has the ability to create bookings. So a customer can buy something or add money on his chipcard. So there is a table called 'bookings' where a id, customer id, price and bookingtyp is stored.
 I have started my program and let it read all bookings and create a current budget of the customer like 300$. If I left my program running and add an entry to the bookings table by hand and then let my program read the bookings table again the amount increases/decreases like it should. If however I now change one of the prices and let the program once again read all bookings it's not updating. 
 So there seems to be a problem when updating an entry but not when adding something to a table.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my. There are so many things that are wrong with this. Let's solve your problem first. Your formbean is instantiated with an IP value of `192.168.178.21`. You use this in your JSP to lookup the record using the method `cjc.find_XML(Cardreader.class, readerIP);`. You're looking it up by IP and not the ID. It does not matter that you changed the ID. That is why the result is the same.

About the code itself

- Never use code inside a JSP. A JSP is a view. If you can, do not use a JSP at all. Use HTML and a templating engine (like Velocity) or a framework like Angular that will bind the data to HTML elements without requiring more code.
- Your mileage may vary but I've found that codegen (like the one you have for the web service client) and a multitude of other frameworks only tend to cloud what you're trying to do. You're invoking a JSP that invokes a REST client on the server side to lookup a value in the database; which then compiles this monster and runs it dynamically only to forward a success to the client side.
- Please take a look at AJAX requests and how web frameworks implement them. You'll save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't exactly understand what you meant. I want to lookup the reader with the id: 192.168.178.21 and then extract the cardid from that which is 1004 in this case. When I change the id: 1004 from reader: 192.168.178.21 to 1002 in the database while the program is running in the background I expect my program to find 1002 if I ask again but instead it is still giving me back 1004. The reader id is still the same of course.

Answer (score 0):

I am to late for answering this but right answer always helps.

In your presistance.xml file change shared-cache-mode to NONE